# vor oder von, mit Dativ Plural?

Tags: preposition, dative

> Der kleine Junge hat keine Angst vor Tieren.

oder

> Der kleine Junge hat keine Angst von Tieren.

Comment: "von + Dativ" hat meist die Bedeutung eines Genitivs. Die "Angst von Tieren" ist also die "Angst der Tiere", d.h. die Tiere haben Angst.

Answer (score 1):

Das ist unabhängig von Plural oder Singular: "Angst haben vor" ist eine fixe Wendung:

> Er hat Angst vor allen Tieren.
> Er hat Angst vor einem Tier.